# Visual studio references through master method with T object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I have have problem with references on methods in my project. You [can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJsvL.png) the 3 methods in different classes and important is that `onSave` of class `RSoubor` with 2 references:

```cs
45 references
protected abstract T onSave(T DOToSave);

99+ references
public T Save(T DOToSave)
{
    if (OnPreSave != null)
        OnPreSave (DOToSave);
    T o = onSave(DOToSave);
    if (OnPostSave != null)
        OnPostSave(DOToSave);
    return o;
}

99 references
public class RSoubor : Repository<DOSoubor>, IRSoubor
{
    2 references
    protected override DOSoubor onSave(DOSoubor DOToSave)
    {
        OracleParameter OutPar = DbOra. ParamOut("p_guid_out", OracleDbType. Raw);
        DbParameter[] dbParams = new[]
        {
            OutPar,
            transaction. DB. ParamIn ("p_guid_dokumentu", DOToSave. GuidDokumentu, F
        };
    }
}
```

I know there are many references on method onSave in RSoubor class through master method `public T Save(T DOToSave)`.

How can I find all references on method `onSave` of class `RSoubor` which is in method `public T Save(T DOToSave)`? Do I need some plugin or change settings?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a built-in "Find All References" feature.
For example, I view a reference to an attribute. Right-click the property and click "Find All References".

[image]

Then I can see all references to that property.

[image]

The search scope can be filtered in two places as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I added the the references for methods in code. You can see 2 references on method 'OnSave' and this reference is to 'public T Save(T DOToSave)' and 'protected abstract T onSave(T DOToSave)', but I want to see references for my method 'OnSave' through  'public T Save(T DOToSave)' in my project. There is at least 6 references to to method 'OnSave' but not directly because its called through 'public T Save(T DOToSave)'.

Comment: @RobinBednar Hi, it seems that [View Call Hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/call-hierarchy?view=vs-2022) can meet your needs. It will show you every method that calls the function and every method that the function calls.